# Getting started with Backbone and a RESTful API

Tags: rest, backbone.js

In Backbone, I have a `User` model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/api/user'
});
```

Next, I instantiate a user object:

```
var user = new User({ id: "123" });
```

Then I call:

```
user.fetch();
```

Upon inspection of the networks pane in Web Inspector, it appears that an API call is being made to `/api/user` when calling the `fetch` method on `user`. My question is simply this: should I not expect it to make an API call to `/api/user/123`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a model outside of the collection, so you need to set the urlroot

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url