# GET the join of two tables using a REST api

Tags: javascript, sqlite, rest

I'm fairly new to using REST to retrieve data from a database. I'm hoping to make a website which has an SQLite database on it. It seems Backbone.js will be a good fit for what I'm trying to do, and it says they interact well with a RESTful API to get data from a database. I read [Understand Backbone.js REST calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504235/understand-backbone-js-rest-calls) to get a better understanding of how REST works.

I found this simple API https://github.com/alixaxel/ArrestDB to get data from an SQLite database.

What I am still not getting is how (if possible) to JOIN two tables.

For example, I have a Books table with BookID, Title and AuthorID, and an Authors table with AuthorID, First Name, Last Name, Age. AuthorID in the Books table is a foreign key to the Authors table.

If I use ArrestDB and go to http://api.mysite.com/books/ I'll get a JSON response of the books, and http://api.mysite.com/authors/ I'll get a JSON response from the Authors. How do I get all the books with the full information of their respective authors? This would be accomplished in SQL using a JOIN. Do I have to merge them manually in Javascript?

Comment: Find a more robust REST library that is also better documented and more current

Comment: Any suggestions? I really just need a wrapper around my sqlite db

Comment: Lots of different php frameworks around that you could use. Take a look at http://cacodaemon.de/index.php?id=48 for example

Comment: I see what you're saying. That's a lot more customizable. What would the GET request look like for a JOIN? A URL to a non-existent database? For example http://api.mysite.com/fullbooks/ which would to the JOIN on both Books and Authors and return the JSON response

Comment: Name the route anything you want and do the join inside it. URL and database tables don't have to use same name conventions...it's up to you whatever you use and whatever data processing you do inside that route

Comment: Maybe consider turning your comments into answer

Comment: Typically, in REST, a join of related resources is left up to the client. As a client, I would send a request to get the books collection. Then I would send requests, in parallel, to retrieve the author representation for each book.